# Calculating the Lyapunov index of elements of a matrix.

Tags: dynamical-systems, random-matrices

In Random Dynamical Systems - Arnold Ludwig, Example 3.3.9.

The cocycle generated by a random matrix:
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & c\\
0 & b
\end{array}\right)$$

is given by:

$$\Phi(n,\omega)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a_{n-1}\cdots a_{0} & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1}\cdots a_{k+1}c_kb_{k-1}\cdots b_{0}\\
0 & b_{n-1}\cdots b_{0}
\end{array}\right).$$

In part (iii) the Lyapunov index of the individual elements of $\Phi$ are then determined. Trivially we have $\lambda(\phi_{11}) = \mathbb{E}\log|a|$ and $\lambda(\Phi_{22})=\mathbb{E}\log|b|$, but then the example goes on without any explanation and determines that the index:  $$ \lambda(\Phi_{12})\leq\max\{\lambda(\Phi_{11}),\lambda(\Phi_{22})\}.$$

I assume that this somehow follows from:

$$\lambda(f+g)\leq\max\{\lambda(f),\lambda(g)\},$$

but I'm not sure. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this hardly needs a justification. One knows that $\prod\limits_{k=1}^na_{n-k}=\mathrm e^{n\alpha+o(n)}$ for some $\alpha$ and that $\prod\limits_{k=1}^nb_{n-k}=\mathrm e^{n\beta+o(n)}$ for some $\beta$ and one considers $s_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1}\cdots a_{k+1}c_kb_{k-1}\cdots b_{0}$.

Let $\lambda\gt\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$, then $a_{n-1}\cdots a_{k+1}c_kb_{k-1}\cdots b_{0}\lt\mathrm e^{(n-k-1)\lambda+C}c_k\mathrm e^{k\lambda+C}=c_k\mathrm e^{n\lambda+C}$ where the value of $C$ may vary from one occurrence to the next. Since $\sum\limits_{k=0}^nc_k=O(n)$, this yields $s_n\leqslant\mathrm e^{n\lambda+C+O(\log n)}$, hence the Lyapunov exponent $\sigma$ of $(s_n)$ is such that $\sigma\leqslant\lambda$. This holds for every $\lambda\gt\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$ hence $\sigma\leqslant\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$.

Comment: Thanks again for saving the day :)

Comment: After a second think about this:  Observing the inequality $s_n\leq e^{n\lambda + C + O(\log n)}$, surely if $\lambda < 0$ we have the $O(\log n)$ dominating, which means that $\sigma \leq \max\{\alpha,\beta , 0\}$ ... Or is this just completely wrong?

Comment: "surely if λ<0 we have the O(logn) dominating" Surely not, actually $O(\log n)=o(n)$ hence $n\lambda+C+O(\log n)=\lambda n+o(n)$, whatever the value of $\lambda$ is.

Comment: Thanks. If the $b_i$ terms happened to be constants $=1$, would the condition be $\sigma\leq\max\{\alpha,0\}$?

Comment: If every $b_k$ is $1$, the exponent $\beta$ is $0$, isn't it? So...

Comment: Exactly. (EXTRA CHARACTERS)